# How to execute two functions sequently in python?

Tags: python

How to execute two functions sequently in python?
for example,
there is a python script:
`test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import shutil

def copy_folder():
    shutil.copytree('/var/www/project-one', '/var/www/project-two')

def modify_file():
    with open('/var/www/project-two/public/index.php', "r+") as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.write(read_data.replace('vendor/autoload.php', '../project-one/vendor/autoload.php'))

def trigger():
    copy_folder() #copy a folder
    modify_file()  # modify a file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trigger()
```

There are three functions in above script,

1. `copy_folder()` copies  folder `project-one`,and saves it as `project-two`.
2. `modify_file()` modifies a file in`project-two`.
3. `trigger()` combines the two steps above.

**Question：**
Executing `copy_folder()` and `modify_file()` manually,it is ok. But executing `trigger()`,there is an error,it looks like `modify_file()` starts running when `copy_folder()` is not complete,so how to let them execute sequently?

Comment: It suppose to be ok the way you do it. Have you tried to debug ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html ) and see what is really happening there?

Comment: I think you can add return statement to copy_folder() and check if it returns for example zero and run  modify_file() , but am not sure that's the best way

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Looks like a race condition, the copy is not finished before modify is triggered. Wait 1-2 s before using `time.sleep()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import shutil
import time

def copy_folder():
    shutil.copytree('/var/www/project-one', '/var/www/project-two')

def modify_file():
    with open('/var/www/project-two/public/index.php', "r+") as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.write(read_data.replace('vendor/autoload.php', '../project-one/vendor/autoload.php'))

def trigger():
    copy_folder() #copy a folder
    time.sleep(2)  # Give some time for copy to finish. 2 seconds in this case.
    modify_file()  # modify a file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trigger()
```